# Create an Interval class with desired format

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, arguments, repr

Im trying to create a class called Interval that if given 1 parameter a, it creates it in the format [a,a], and if given 2 parameters a and b, it creates it in the format [a,b]. See the following code

```
class Interval():

   def __init__(self,left,*args):

       if args:
           self.left=left
           self.right=args
       else:
           self.left=left
           self.right=left


   def __repr__(self):
       return("[{},{}]".format(self.left,self.right))
```

Now when i have only one parameter it prints it out in the desired format, but with 2 parameters i get a paranthesis inside the brackets, see below:

```
    a = Interval(1)
    b = Interval(2,4)
    print (a)
    print (b)
```

Prints out:

```
    [1,1]
    [2,(4,)]
```

Why does this happen? Any help appreciated,  thanks.

Comment: because variable-positional arguments will *always be a tuple*, i.e. `args` is a tuple when you do `self.right = args`

Comment: You probably simply want an optional parameter, e.g. `def __init__(self,left,right=None):` then `self.right = right if right is not None else left`

Comment: Not an answer to your question; however, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinterval might be of interest to you.

Comment: You might be interested in [`mpu.datastructures.Interval`](https://mpu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datastructures.html#mpu.datastructures.Interval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'args' is a tuple, that's why you get the paranthesis.

```
class Interval():

   def __init__(self,left,*args):

       if args:
           self.left=left
           self.right=args[0]
       else:
           self.left=left
           self.right=left


   def __repr__(self):
       return("[{},{}]".format(self.left,self.right))
```

Answer (score 0):

To be as generic as possible, you can try this:

```
class Interval():
  def __init__(self,left,*args):
     if args:
        self.left=left
        self.right=args
     else:
        self.left=left
        self.right=left
  def __repr__(self):
      return("[{},{}]".format(self.left,','.join(map(str, self.right))))
i = Interval(4, 4)
print(i)
```

Output:

```
[4,4]
```